# Check if awaited IActionResult returns a 204

Tags: c#, .net, http-status-code-204

The method below returns a 204 if completed successfully, but I'm having trouble checking the status code. It's an IActionResult, in Postman it returns an empty body with a status code of 204.

```
IActionResult response = await _benchmarkingClient.CheckAndLoadJobDetails(checkAndLoadJobDetailsRequest);

context.Logger.LogLine($"Response StatusCode: {response}");
            
if (response.StatusCode == 204)
 {...}
```

The above code is unhappy because StatusCode doesn't even exist on response.

If I remove the status code if block, the above returns this error:

```
"The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true.
```

This JsonException seems correct, since I don't except any Json. I only need to capture the status code, but have not been able to figure out how to do it.

Edit: This is `CheckAndLoadJobDetails`:

```
...
  public async Task<IActionResult> CheckAndLoadJobDetails(CheckAndLoadJobDetailsRequest checkAndLoadJobDetailsRequest, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        try
        {
            var projectId = checkAndLoadJobDetailsRequest.ProjectId;
            var tenantId = checkAndLoadJobDetailsRequest.TenantId;

            var project = await _apiService.GetLaborApiClient().GetProject(projectId);
            
            var salaryScheduleId = project.ActiveSalaryScheduleId;
            
            var jobDetailsSheet = await _spreadsheetService.GetSpreadsheet(
                $"{SalaryScheduleObjectPrefix}{salaryScheduleId}",
                _config["LcmS3Bucket"], 
                _jobDetailsSheetSpec
            );
            
            if (jobDetailsSheet.Success)
            {
                var loadedJobDetails = await LoadJobDetails(
                    tenantId,
                    project.TenantId,
                    project.ProjectId!,
                    project.ProjectName!,
                    salaryScheduleId,
                    cancel
                );
                
                if (loadedJobDetails)
                { 
                    return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent);
                }
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
            throw new BadHttpRequestException(
                $"Job details sheet not found",
                StatusCodes.Status409Conflict
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.GetType() == typeof(BadHttpRequestException))
            {
                throw ex;
            } 
            throw new BadHttpRequestException(
                $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}",
                StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `HttpResponseMessage` object that has the `StatusCode` property is somewhere inside the `CheckAndLoadJobDetails` method. That method needs to be modified to understand 204, and probably return `null` because ASP.NET Web API returns a 204 response when an action method returns `Ok(null)`. Symmetry.

Comment: It would help if you 1) showed the contents of the `CheckAndLoadJobDetails` method, and 2) changed `var` to the actual type when you post your code so we can see what you're dealing with since we don't have tooling (e.g. Visual Studio) to tell us what it is.

Comment: If the API is returning 204 for a request that's intended to get something, it's almost certainly buggy. and needs to return `NotFound()` instead of `Ok(null)` when it doesn't find the identified resource. It depends on what it means to "check and load job details".

Comment: @madreflection ok, I've updated with what CheckAndLoadJobDetails returns, and the type of response. please let me know if this helps

Comment: Not helpful. For one, I asked for the client, and what you've shown is the API's action method. My comments about the API are tangential the issue; the issue is in how the client handles (or rather, doesn't handle) the 204 response. Next, why is the client method returning `IActionResult`? The client shouldn't know about this type, as it's just an abstraction for the various ways in which the *server* can return a response. The client should only know about the concrete response structures. Finally, you need to show a complete method definition, not a narrow slice of the body.

Comment: @madreflection I didn't think it was.. by the client, do you mean this?

`[Post("/api/v1/jobdetails/load")]
    Task<IActionResult> CheckAndLoadJobDetails(
      CheckAndLoadJobDetailsRequest checkAndLoadJobDetailsRequest);`
This is the client method for that slice of code above. I had trouble returning a 204 (what I'm instructed to return) without using `IActionResult`. 

Also, I'll include the entire method above, even though I don't see how it's more helpful than the part that shows what's being returned.

Comment: The client is `_benchmarkingClient`, its type, and its methods, and particularly the `CheckAndLoadJobDetails` method in question.

Comment: No, that's the API controller's action method. It's the server. It's *not* the client.

Comment: @madreflection that's the method from a file called `IBenchmarkingApiClient`, it's being pulled directly into my current file (a lambda, btw). 
The below is happening in the lambda, after which i make the call (which is `response` above):
```
_benchmarkingClient = RestService.For<IBenchmarkingApiClient>(
                new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://benchmarking-api.dev"),
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(900),
                }
            );
```

Comment: `RestService.For` appears to be creating a proxy for you, so the client is something you can't see, therefore you don't have control over how it handles the 204 response, unless it has some sort of configuration for that handling.

Comment: @madreflection is there a better way than `RestService.For`? I used this because I saw it previously used in a similar lambda.

Comment: You could always write your own typed client. It takes work, but it gives you the best control. You could look for another library. The big thing to note here is that encountering a problem and saying "we always did it this way before" is a good opportunity to ask yourself why it was done that way before. It may have had benefits that no longer outweigh the restrictions it imposed in order to gain them. Accepting "we always did it this way before" as the reason to keep doing it is self-defeating.

Comment: [Typed Clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#typed-clients)

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is returning the correct type and you just need to verify that it is a 204 response, then a cast might work. I say might as in there could be other issues that are not known, especially if you are attempting to manipulate the response when there is no content, 204 response.

Anyway, in order to check the type and the status code of the response, this will work.

```
var response = await _benchmarkingClient.CheckAndLoadJobDetails(checkAndLoadJobDetailsRequest);

if (response is NoContentResult)
{
    var result = (NoContentResult)response;
    var statusCode = result.StatusCode;
}
```

`NoContentResult` is a class that inherits from `IActionResult` and is used as a No Content 204 response. This will check the type of `response` and if it is a `NoContentResult`, will hit the if block. In the if block, cast it to a `NoContentResult` then grabbing the status code is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's a separate interface for `IActionResult` that happens to have a status code: [`IStatusCodeActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.istatuscodeactionresult?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Your logic then becomes:

```
if (response is IStatusCodeActionResult responseWithStatusCode &&  
    responseWithStatusCode.StatusCode == 204)
{...}
```

…or to be even more explicit:

```
if (response is IStatusCodeActionResult responseWithStatusCode &&  
    responseWithStatusCode.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NoResult)
{...}
```